# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView.decode

Tags: java, android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I had an image scanning activity with openCV infrastructure before. However, even though there is no code change at the moment, it gives an error and restarts the application. It gives a warning to a method in Asynctask.

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView.decode(byte[], int, int, int[])`

```
2022-08-07 19:34:48.610 10271-10357/com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive, PID: 10271
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$AsyncFutureTask.done(AsyncTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView.decode(byte[], int, int, int[]) (tried Java_com_netdatasoft_android_divvydrive_scanner_views_CameraView_decode and Java_com_netdatasoft_android_divvydrive_scanner_views_CameraView_decode___3BII_3I)
    at com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView.decode(Native Method)
    at com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView.access$200(CameraView.java:35)
    at com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView$PreviewFrameAsyncTask.doInBackground(CameraView.java:274)
    at com.netdatasoft.android.divvydrive.scanner.views.CameraView$PreviewFrameAsyncTask.doInBackground(CameraView.java:262)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:389)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:292) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

Comment: You're either missing a .so file, or you have the name or signature wrong for either your java side binding for the decode function, or for the C side implementation.  Or you forgot to load the native library

Comment: thank you very much. I provided the solution by replacing old library files using GIT.